# After upgrading to Symfony 3 a custom FormType gives problems

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've been using an slightly adapted version of the [OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle](https://github.com/mhauptma73/OpenSPG/tree/develop/src/LocationBundle) on Symfony 2.8 as LocationType/MapType into my own bundle. After upgrading to Symfony 3.2, when trying to save the data filled in for the Location I get the error

> Neither the property "lat" nor one of the methods "getLat()", "lat()", "isLat()", "hasLat()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "LocationBundle\Form\LocationType".

The custom FormType is included via LocationType::class into another FormType ([NodeType](https://github.com/mhauptma73/OpenSPG/blob/develop/src/ManagementBundle/Form/NodeType.php)).

I've been looking through changes in Symfony, specially the Form component, to see if something affects the way data is read/written into the Entity, but couldn't find anything.

The code in LocationType, where I include the MapType, is

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('LatLng', MapType::class, array(
            'default_lat' => '37.06394430056685',
            'default_lng' => '-3.09814453125',
            'map_width' => 600,
            'type' => HiddenType::class
        ))
        ;
}
```

In the final view (Browser) the fields are collected with

```
<input id="node_Location_LatLng_lat" name="node[Location][LatLng][lat]" value="36.945971" type="hidden"><input id="node_Location_LatLng_lng" name="node[Location][LatLng][lng]" value="-3.1785935000000336" type="hidden">
```

Shouldn't my entity receive the Array LatLng instead of its components? That's how it worked before updating to Symfony 3.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to define the missing methods? Do I have to implement a ValueTransformer.. but then, why it wasn't necessary before?

Comment: Can you provide parts of the code you are using.

Comment: It says specifically `This bundle is compatible with Symfony 2.1.`

Comment: although there are some commits to make this bundle work with symfony 3 there are some issues which prevent that, most prominent the type which is not allowed to be a string like `'text'`anymore but should be `TextType::class`

Comment: Sorry... I just realised that I hadn't updated the repository and were linking to the wrong places. Really sorry about giving wrong information :-( I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In MapType::configureOptions() I defined `'data_class' => LocationType::class` when it should have been `'data_class' => 'LocationBundle\Entity\Location'`.

That must have happened when converting the code to Symfony3 rules. I leave the question here for others... and maybe even myself.